# How do roots absorb water instead of presence of waxy - material suberin in the form of casparian strips on the wall of endodermis?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

I found that in the endodermis, the tangential and radial walls have deposition of the waxy, and hence water-impermeable, material suberin in the form of casparian strips. The endodermis comes before the vascular bundle so how is water absorbed in roots?

Comment: Read this (especially the function part):
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endodermis